# Why doesn't the value of variable from another module get propagated to other functions even after it's set?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, global-variables

The variable SCRIPT_ENV gets set correctly in main block but that value does not propagate to other functions.
Here's my full working code:

```py
import argparse
import settings
from multiprocessing import Pool


def set_brokers_and_cert_path():
    brokers = None
    cert_full_path = None
    print("I am here man\n\n {0}".format(settings.SCRIPT_ENV))
    if settings.SCRIPT_ENV == "some value":
        brokers = # use these brokers
        cert_full_path = settings.BASE_CERT_PATH + "test_env/"
    if settings.SCRIPT_ENV == "some other value":
        brokers = # use those brokers
        cert_full_path = settings.BASE_CERT_PATH + "new_env/"
    return brokers, cert_full_path


def func_b(partition):
    kafka_brokers, cert_full_path = set_brokers_and_cert_path()
    producer = KafkaProducer(bootstrap_servers=kafka_brokers,
                             security_protocol='SSL',
                             ssl_check_hostname=True,
                             ssl_cafile=cert_full_path +'cacert.pem',
                             ssl_certfile=cert_full_path + 'certificate.pem',
                             ssl_keyfile=cert_full_path + 'key.pem',
                             max_block_ms=1200000,
                             value_serializer=lambda v: json.dumps(v).encode('utf-8'),
                             key_serializer=str.encode
                             )
    try:
        producer.send(settings.KAFKA_TOPIC,
                      value="some val",
                      key="some key",
                      timestamp_ms=int(time.time()),
                      headers=[some headers],
                      partition=partition)
        producer.flush()
    except AssertionError as e:
        print("Error in partition: {0}, {1}".format(partition, e))


def main():
  with Pool(settings.NUM_PROCESSES) as p:
    p.map(func_b, [i for i in range(0, 24)])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--env", help="Environment against which the script needs to run")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.env:
        settings.SCRIPT_ENV = args.env
        main()
    else:
        raise Exception("Please pass env argument. Ex: --env test/accept")
```

In the line "I am here man", it prints `None` as the value of `SCRIPT_ENV`.
Here, `SCRIPT_ENV` gets set perfectly in the `if __name__ == "__main__"` block, but in `func_a`, it comes as `None`.

contents of settings.py:

```
KAFKA_TOPIC = "some topic"
NUM_PROCESSES = 8
NUM_MESSAGES = 1000
SCRIPT_ENV = None
NUM_PARTITIONS = 24
TEST_BROKERS = [some brokers]
ACCEPT_BROKERS = [some brokers]
BASE_CERT_PATH = "base path"
```

I run it like this:

```bash
python <script.py> --env <value>
```

Comment: Where do you call `func_a()`?

Comment: There's no `SOME_VAR`, do you mean `settings.SCRIPT_ENV`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5442910/how-to-use-multiprocessing-pool-map-with-multiple-arguments

Comment: yep, same question above , Where and When fo you call func_a() ?? Next time try with smaller minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry. Updated the code. func_a() is nothing but "set_brokers_and_cert_path"

Answer (score -1):

In your code example a few references are missing, without which it is not executable. First, we should find out the program parts that lead to the behavior you describe.
I do not suppose the `argparse` to be crucial. Basically you change an attribute in the module instance `settings` and call `main()`, so you can reduce the last part of the program to a few lines:

```py
settings.SCRIPT_ENV = "test"
main()
```

Function `main()` propagates function `func_b()` over multiple processes. Function `func_b()` itself performs following steps:

1. Call of function `set_brokers_and_cert_path()` (you earlier named `func_a()`)
2. Create an instance of `KafkaProducer` (`producer`)
3. Send some data per `producer`.

I cannot see that the created instance has any effect on the content of `settings.SCRIPT_ENV`, so I reduce function `func_b()` as well and leave only the first function call (for simplicity I take the original name `func_a()`).

Function `func_a()` (aka `set_brokers_and_cert_path()`) likewise has no apparent influence on `settings.SCRIPT_ENV`, since only a few strings are generated.
For debugging purposes I left the output of the text variables in the function.

All together, I come up with the following executable minimal example, which does not recreate for me the problem you describe (see output).
You can take this example and transfer it piece by piece back to your code and then see which part of the program leads to the problems.

```py
import settings
from multiprocessing import Pool


def func_a():
    print("I am here man\n{0}\n".format(settings.SCRIPT_ENV))


def func_b(partition):
    func_a()


def main():
  with Pool(settings.NUM_PROCESSES) as p:
    p.map(func_b, [i for i in range(0, 24)])


settings.SCRIPT_ENV = "Test"
main()
```

### Output

```
I am here man
Test

I am here man
Test

I am here man
Test

I am here man
Test

...
```

@RajatBhardwaj, at this point, it is up to you to decide whether you want to participate in finding a solution.

All others who are not interested in a solution would do well not to criticize solutions without having understood its intention.

Comment: This isn't OPs code at all. Their code never calls `func_a`.

Comment: @Axe319, it's a simplified version of the code. His `set_brokers_and_cert_path()` called in `func_b()` is my `func_a()`. No reason for a down vote!

Comment: That makes a massive difference if `set_brokers_and_cert_path` is in another module. The point is, OP's code isn't working and this code is. That means there's at least something functionally different about this code. We don't know what that is until they include more details in their post. Even if it would be exactly the same as yours, how is "it works on my machine" an answer?